# Prusa i3 jerking during printing

Tags: print-quality, prusa-i3, y-axis

I have a Prusa i3 and during the print, it will start jerking which makes a noise that sounds like something is going wrong. At first, I thought it was the infill since there is a gap in between the layers which this picture shows (I have ripped off the bad layers to see if I can get any use out of it. The video shows the bad layers). For reference the "wall" along the outside is 2.1 mm.

[image] Then about 70% of the way through the print, the Y layers started to shift so I thought that the jerking was a result of this. This is a video of what is happening https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1afjwyzl8hqej9/IMG_0403.MOV?dl=0

So is this the infill that is causing the jerking or is there something that I should fix on the printer that will stop jerking?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well that is unique. I would say if you only see this after the printer has been running a while then your electronics are likely overheating. Put a fan on it and report back.

Otherwise and also I would reflash the electronics..

Comment: Should I put the fan on the main board?

Comment: Yeah see if that fixes it. If so 3d print a case that has a fan holder.